# Write an equation for the perimeter of a rectangle and solve for $x$ given dimensions and perimeter

Tags: area, rectangles

I found an interesting math problem.
**The perimeter of rectangle is *24 cm*, and its dimensions are *2/x* and *5/(x+1)*.

Form an equation and find the value of x.** I got stuck with 2 values of x: *x=-2/3* or *x=1/4*. I cannot understand which one to use because if we can use both of them, one side will have a negative length.

Comment: Dimensions will be positive...

Comment: Of course, they will. But the task is to find the value of x, not the dimensions.

Comment: This happens often in physics. A system may be governed by an equation that has multiple *mathematical* solutions, but only one *physical* solution.

Comment: If $x$ is negative, $2/x$ will be too.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting the first solution $(x=-2/3)$ back into the length of the rectangle, we get $l=-2/x=-3$. This is clearly not possible as the length can never be negative. Hence the first solution is invalid and can be neglected.

Answer (score 0):

The perimeter is given by

$$P=2(L+l)=2(\frac{5}{x+1}+\frac 2x)=24$$
with $x>0$

thus

$$\frac{5}{x+1}+\frac 2x =12$$

and

$$5x+2(x+1)=12x(x+1)$$
then
$$12x^2+12x-5x-2x-2=0$$
or
$$12x^2+5x-2=0$$
$$\delta=25+96=121$$
the positive root is
$$x=\frac{-5+11}{24}=\frac 14$$

Then
$$L=\frac 2x=8\; \text{ and } \; l=4$$

Comment: One of dimensions given is 2/x, not 1/x

Comment: The task is to find the value of x.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the sides are given by $\frac2x, \frac5{x+1}$, and these must be positive because lengths are non-negative.

Therefore you have been asked to solve the system of equations:

$\frac2x\gt0, \frac5{x+1}\gt0, \frac2x+\frac5{x+1}=12$, and the answer is $x=\frac14$.